# Copy specific data to other sheet (with script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, filter, scripting, copy-paste

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mpALs4rdNj-TFFgCQ0CEBP453v-FfQJR_bBxOzQakWU/edit#gid=1256640730
(Anyone with the link can view this spreadsheet)

[image]

I have a "masterlist" sheet collect data from Google Forms and I need the script to copy the data to the related sheet according to their "Location"...The name of other sheet is named from "Location"

````
Example 1  

Sheet 1: Contain all the data (Master List)
Name......Address...............................Location
Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Kedah
Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Kedah
Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Penang
Stone......5,Jae Road,22222...............Penang  

Sheet 2: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Location-Kedah Only)
Name......Address...............................Location
Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Kedah
Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Kedah

Sheet 3: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Location-Penang Only)
Name......Address...............................Location
Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Penang
Stone......5,Jae Road,22222.........Penang```
````

---

```
Example 2

Sheet 1: Contain all the data (Master List)
Name.....Gender
Bryan.....Male
Mei.....Female
Lily.....Female
xx.....Female
xx.....Male  

Sheet 2: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Gender-Female Only)
Name.....Gender
xx.....Female
Lily.....Female
Mei.....Female

Sheet 3: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Gender-Male Only)
Name.....Gender
Bryan.....Male
```

---

```
function copyDataUniqueToColG() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Master List');
  const shsr=2;//data start row on master list
  const shhr=1;//master list header row
  const hA=sh.getRange(shhr,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map(function(r){return[r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6]]})[0];
  const vs=sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const base='Sheet';
  let shts=ss.getSheets();
  //shts.forEach(function(s,i){if(s.getName()!='Master List'){ss.deleteSheet(s);}});//delete all other sheets
  const gvs=sh.getRange(shsr,7,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  const s=new Set(gvs);
  const g=[...s];//g has unique values now
  g.forEach(function(v,i){
    let sA=[];
    ss.getSheets().forEach(function(obj){sA.push(obj.getName())});
    if(sA.indexOf(v)==-1){ss.insertSheet(v);}
    let aA=[]
    aA.push(hA);//start with header row
    vs.forEach(function(r,j){
      //compare to column G value
      if(r[6]==v) {
        aA.push([r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6]]);//add rows that match
      }
    });
    let dsh=ss.getSheetByName(v);
    dsh.getRange(1,1,aA.length,aA[0].length).setValues(aA);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();//not really necessary but fun to watch the progress
  });
}
```

Comment: can you share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: done sharing the code to the question.. but the code is not working for me..

Comment: Provide [mcve]. **Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.**

Comment: =QUERY('Master List'!A:M, "where G = 'Melaka'", 1)
the result from this formula is exactly what I need, but I need it in "script editor" instead of formula

Comment: You could use the method [Range.setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=de#setformulaformula) example: `Range.setFormula("=QUERY('Master List'!A:M, 'where G = "Melaka"', 1)")`

Comment: Hi Aerials, can you tell me how to use this with Full App Script.. Because I am new to write script...and I not sure how to use the above script for all sheet (all location) "melaka,kedah,pahang...etc"

Comment: I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63280512/4243927) with the Apps Script code. If it works for you please accept it. See [How-to-ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I see.. but it's not working and I think there's some misunderstanding. Actually I don't need to set the formula, I just need the script for copy paste from master sheet to the related sheet... Not sure whether you get it. Anyway thanks for your effort..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code to solve your problem:

```js
function distributeMasterToSheets(){
  // Get all sheets except master list
  var allSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var destinationSheets = allSheets.slice(1);
  // And set the sheet name dependent formula in range A1 
  destinationSheets.forEach(
    function(sheet){
      sheet.getRange("A1").setFormula("=QUERY('Master List'!A:M,\"select * where G = '"+sheet.getName()+"'\",1)")
    }
  )  
}
```

The following documentation is where the methods used are explained, I suggest you go through some quickstarts to get the hang of it.

---

#### References:

- [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Extending Google Sheets guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

in `Melaka` sheet paste this in A2:

```
=FILTER('Master List'!A:M, 'Master List'!G:G="Melaka")
```

[image]

etc for the rest...

---

or you can use this in A1:

```
=QUERY('Master List'!A:M, "where G = 'Melaka'", 1)
```

---

or if you want to use Apps Script, the method [Range.setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=de#setformulaformula) can be used:

```js
Range.setFormula("=QUERY('Master List'!A:M, 'where G = \"Melaka\"', 1)")
```

Comment: is it possible to make it as a script instead of formula? because I'm going to edit and make changes in the "Melaka" Sheet

Comment: yes, thats also possible - I corrected your question...

Comment: I means the function scripts in (Tools>Script Editors), instead of adding formula in A1 / A2

Comment: Yes I need to use Apps Script. Thank you so much for your reply. By the way, can you provide me with Full App Script.. Because I am new to write script...and I not sure how to use the above script for all sheet (all location) "melaka,kedah,pahang...etc"